# How to get NodeJS to evaluate multiple traditional JS files

Tags: javascript, node.js

We are using nodejs as an js engine to evaluate some student scripts on the server side so we can test their correctness.

Is there a way we can 'require' or 'import' multiple traditional .js files? We need to include submissions from multiple users. Or I'd have to concatenate the files?

Comment: can you give a sample student script and how you plan to evaluate?Psuedo code is also fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Node.JS (like most high level languages) supports dynamic import. If you have a list of files, for example

```
var files = ["student1.js", "student2.js", "student3.js", ...];
```

then you can simply do

```
files.forEach(function(f) {
    try {
        require(f);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Error in file: "+f);
    }
});
```

this will automatically import and evaluate these files. Note that it might throw an exception (because of errors in files),so that's why it is wrapped with `try{}catch{}`.

However if you keep scripts in database and in Node.JS you only have them as strings then you could use eval:

```
var scripts = ["var x = 1;", "console.log('test');", ...];
scripts.forEach(function(s) {
    try {
        eval(s);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Error in script:\n"+s);
    }
});
```

Of course "traditional" (I assume that by that you mean browser-side JavaScript) scripts may not be compatibile with Node.JS (for example there is no `window` in Node.JS).

**WARNING:** Note that both methods are unsafe (users can upload malicious scripts), so perhaps the best idea would be to spawn a separate Node.JS process (in restricted environment) for each one of them. You could write a script for that as well, it's just a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. When I was looking around, all I found was the modular solution that doesn't work for browser code :P